Inequality Involving Concave Functions
Assume that $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_+ $ is a concave, non-decreasing and positive function. Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a finite set consisting of $ 0\leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq \ldots \leq x_n$. Further, let $ X $ be a random variable supported on $\mathbb{X}$.
I am interested in the following inequality:
$$
\frac{
    f(x_n) - \mathbb{E}[f(X)]
}{
    \sqrt{
        \mathbb{E}\left[
            \left(f(X) - \mathbb{E}[f(X)]\right)^2
        \right]
    }
}
\leq
\frac{
    x_n - \mathbb{E}[X]
}{
    \sqrt{
        \mathbb{E}\left[
            \left(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\right)^2
        \right]
    }
}
$$
Is this inequality always true under the given conditions? If so, can you provide a proof or some intuition behind why this inequality holds? If not, can you provide a counterexample or conditions under which it might fail?

May I know the source of the problem?

It is true, fairly simple, and reasonably well-known (to people who know it well) in a slightly different form.
Shifting $x_n$ and $f(x_n)$ to $0$, flipping both axes and the fraction, squaring, writing the variance as $E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2$ and adding $1$, we arrive at the following (classical?) version of this inequality:
Let $X\ge 0$ be a random variable, and let $f:[0,+\infty)\to [0,+\infty)$ be a convex increasing function with $f(0)=0$. Then
$$
\frac{E[f(X)^2]}{E[f(X)]^2}\ge \frac{E[X^2]}{E[X]^2}\,.
$$
The proof is a three-liner. First, note that the LHS is invariant under multiplication of $f$ by a positive constant, so we can normalize so that $E[f(X)]=E[X]$. Then
$E[(f(X)-X)_+]=E[(X-f(X))_+]$ (here $a_+=\max(0,a)$). Note that due to the convexity of $f$ and the condition $f(0)=0$, we have $f(x)\le x$ for $x\le x_0$ and $f(x)\ge x$ for $x\ge x_0$ with some $x_0>0$.
Hence
$$
E[(f(X)^2-X^2)_+]\ge E[2x_0(f(X)-X)_+]
\\
=E[2x_0(X-f(X))_+]\ge E[(X^2-f(X)^2)_+]\,, 
$$
whence $E[f(X)^2]\ge E[X^2]$ and we are done.

There is another bounty with some hours left (there is an answer but not sure if it really solves the question) that I feel it could be solved with a version of the inequality you used because what wants to be proved $\sum (p-\frac{1}{n})^2\ge\sum(\frac{p\log 1/p}{\sum p\log 1/p} -\frac{1}{n})^2$ reduces to $\sum p^2\ge\sum(\frac{p\log 1/p}{\sum p\log 1/p})^2$ or $\frac{\sum p^2}{(\sum p)^2}\ge\frac{\sum f(p)^2}{(\sum f(p))^2}$, if you want to look at it.

@Dabed $f(p)=-p \log p$ is concave but not increasing, which makes it challenging (see the existing answer for more details).

@Amir Ah right did follow the proof but put my attention was drawn just to the similitude of the inequalities and didn't think this much trough, thanks.

@Amir Of course, $f(p)=-p\log p$ is not increasing on $(0,1)$ but $-cp\log p+p$ (where $c\in(0,1)$ is the normalizing factor such that $\sum cf(p)=1$) is increasing on the set of $p$'s involved (though it is not at all obvious), and that suffices. Can you finish it from here or should I post the full solution?

@fedja Thank you! If you are not busy now, you may post it as a full solution so that I can award the bounty (it expires shortly).

@Amir Right now I have some other fish to fry, but I'll try to do it later in the day :-)

@fedja  As it expires in 2-3 hours, you may provide a mini answer and then complete it later. Otherwise, I will complete it later. Grilling fish is healthier and faster than frying it :D

@fedja thanks a lot for the answer! Btw, do you recommend a source for inequalities of this type? I read most parts of the "Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class" but didn't find it useful here.

@AlirezaBakhtiari You are welcome. I'm not sure if I know any good textbook that would go over such trickery (maybe Amir can recommend something?), but the idea of the general setup with "one crossing point and balanced sums/integrals" is simple enough to understand just from a couple of examples and it is surprisingly useful.

@fedja I have a new question that is similar to this one, so I think you may be able to help me! I really appreciate that!
